# Flow use session send() method failed?

Tags: session, corda, send

I use session.send() method to send a string, but it returns this error when start flow.

```
[ERROR] 23:43:46+0800 [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Flow raised an error: null. The flow's  
database transaction is missing. {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=Sender,  
L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=ac0b55a7-06da- 
4bef-87da-1f68c85a293e, invocation_id=9e45732f-9ec9-4914-bfa8-aae52a9208f8,  
invocation_timestamp=2021-06-02T15:43:46.233Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=b9ee9f7f- 
ea97-4731-8f62-bc2dd398098e, session_timestamp=2021-06-02T15:43:45.850Z, thread-id=204}
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was mentioned in the Corda slack, so i report it here as well for those who face the same issue.

In that case it was `@Suspendable` that was missing before the `call()` function definition in the flow.